# Hadoop command `hadoop fs -ls` gives ConnectionRefused error

Tags: hadoop

When I run hadoop command like `hadoop fs -ls`, I get following error/warnings:

```
16/08/04 11:24:12 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: Call From master/172.17.100.54 to master:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

Am I doing anything wrong with the hadoop path?

Comment: This `WARN util.NativeCodeLoader` is just a warning, it wont stop it working. You need to look into the `Connection refused`, for example is the host `master` resolvable?

Answer (score 0):

> Hadoop Native Libraries Guide say its some thing to do with
>   installation. please check documentation to resolve this.

[**Native Hadoop Library**](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/NativeLibraries.html)

Hadoop has native implementations of certain components for performance reasons and for non-availability of Java implementations. These components are available in a single, dynamically-linked native library called the native hadoop library. On the *nix platforms the library is named `libhadoop.so.`

**Please note the following:**

It is mandatory to install both the **zlib** and **gzip** development packages on the target platform in order to build the native hadoop library; however, for deployment it is sufficient to install just one package if you wish to use only one codec.
It is necessary to have the correct 32/64 libraries for **zlib**, depending on the 32/64 bit jvm for the target platform, in order to build and deploy the native hadoop library.

***Runtime***

The `bin/hadoop` script ensures that the native hadoop library is on the library path via the system property: `-Djava.library.path=<path>`

During runtime, check the hadoop log files for your MapReduce tasks.

If everything is all right, then: `DEBUG util.NativeCodeLoader - Trying to load the custom-built native-hadoop library... INFO util.NativeCodeLoader - Loaded the native-hadoop library`

If something goes wrong, then: `INFO util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable`

***Check***

NativeLibraryChecker is a tool to check whether native libraries are loaded correctly. You can launch NativeLibraryChecker as follows

```
   $ hadoop checknative -a
   14/12/06 01:30:45 WARN bzip2.Bzip2Factory: Failed to load/initialize native-bzip2 library system-native, will use pure-Java version
   14/12/06 01:30:45 INFO zlib.ZlibFactory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
   Native library checking:
   hadoop: true /home/ozawa/hadoop/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0
   zlib:   true /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
   snappy: true /usr/lib/libsnappy.so.1
   lz4:    true revision:99
   bzip2:  false
```

***Second thing Connection refused is something related to your setup. please double check setup.***
also see the below as pointers..

[Hadoop cluster setup - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661285/hadoop-cluster-setup-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused)

[Hadoop - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905388/hadoop-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused)